# Layout issues, part fixed width, part elastic

Tags: html, css, background, fixed, liquid-layout

I've already had a look through some posts and couldn't find what I was after. I'm designing something in PS at the moment and I can foresee an issue when it comes to coding the design into html+css.

Imagine my centre div, it's `960px`. It's going to have a semi-transparent `.png` as a background. The design is `“full width”` so this div will be contained in a larger div, set to 100% width. This is all ok until I get to the background on this outer div. It's also going to have a .png running the full width of the page. Problem is: I don't want it running through the middle, as it will result in the middle have a double thickness to it, if that makes sense?!

Basically, I need a way to either run a div either side that is elastic, or someway of stopping the background from running across the centre `960px` portion of the browser window.

I have NO idea how this can be achieved, apart from using JS to set widths, which I don’t really want to do.

Any ideas?

Ok, I’ve tried to get the basic issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Bznc/1/

Comment: Why do you need a transparent background?

Comment: because the background behind all this is a texture that I want to partly show through layers stacked on top

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `background-image` only to the wrapping `div`.

Alternatively, if the center and sides need to have different images, give the center `div` a non-transparent `background-color` as well.

Also, you could fake it by using multiple `background-images`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Bznc/4/)

Keep in mind this won't work in old versions of IE, but something as non-essential as background transparency can be excepted as graceful degradation.

Comment: I don’t think that will work. the outer div will have something like a 10px height strip that’s set to repeat-x so it will fill the full width of the page. The centre div (the 960 one) is going to have a different shape (a rectangle) that’s also semi transparent. The idea is the background on `body` will show through all of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a non-transparent background on the center div, so the other background doesn't show through.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9bnHD/

Comment: I’ve added a fiddle so you can see what I mean.